# Indexes not created when running rebuild_index

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm following the Getting Started guide, but when I run `manage.py rebuild_index`, it seems none of my models are indexed.

When I try to search in /search, I get no results and this in the logs:

```
Problem accessing /solr/select/. Reason: no field name specified in query and no defaultSearchField defined in schema.xml
```

Here is my app's **`search_indexes.py`**. It's bit more complex than the guide's model, so maybe it's the reason why it's not working.

```
import datetime

from myproject.apps.lead import Lead, Opportunity

from haystack import site
from haystack.indexes import *

class LeadIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    company = CharField(model_attr='company__name')

    contact_name = MultiValueField()
    contact_city = MultiValueField()
    contact_state = MultiValueField()
    contact_postcode = MultiValueField()
    contact_email = MultiValueField()
    contact_phone = MultiValueField()

    product = CharField(model_attr='product__name')
    campaign = CharField(model_attr='campaign__name')

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Lead.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

    def prepare_contact_name(self, obj):
        return [contact.name for contact in obj.contact_set.order_by('name')]

    def prepare_contact_city(self, obj):
        return [contact.city for contact in obj.contact_set.order_by('city')]

    def prepare_contact_state(self, obj):
        return [contact.state for contact in obj.contact_set.order_by('state')]

    def prepare_contact_postcode(self, obj):
        return [contact.postcode for contact in obj.contact_set.order_by('postcode')]

    def prepare_contact_email(self, obj):
        return [contact.email for contact in obj.contact_set.order_by('email')]

    def prepare_contact_phone(self, obj):
        return [contact.phone for contact in obj.contact_set.order_by('phone')]

site.register(Lead, LeadIndex)
```

And my **`/templates/search/indexes/lead/lead_text.txt`** is just

```
{{ object.company__name }}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your index class needs to inherit from *both* `indexes.SearchIndex` and `indexes.Indexable`.

```
class LeadIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    ...
```

*Please don't use wildcard imports (`*`). It's very bad form and leads to namespace pollution.*